# Developing software for Ubuntu

Tags: development

So I noticed that programs such as `dd` or `Unetbootin` won't work for Windows images, and I wrote a program that does just that. Now it's really just a python script that uses some command line software that comes with Linux, my question is, are there some standards that I must take in mind, like some good practices. For instance is it bad that I ask for root rights?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not bad practice to ask for root privileges.

If you require root privileges more than once during program runtime, then running the entire program as root will probably prove useful.

There aren't really any 'good practices' - if you're looking for a certain piece of advice, ask it as a question **=)**

By the way, the program you've created is called a "GUI front-end" - to the command your using. For example, a program that uses `xrandr` to work is called a "GUI front-end to xrandr".

Comment: even know it's a terminal  application?

Comment: @Daniel Yes, front-ends can be textual.

Comment: @Daniel therefore your program is just a "front-end".